# A handicapped longbowman becomes a sleuth

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember a book series wherein a longbow archer becomes handicapped, and becomes a "detective", which turns out to cause him a few knocks on the head as well. The story takes place in medieval England, and I seem to recall the title of the first one involving the word "Archer".

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Comment: Does this book have any science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: I think so, can't recall the exact stories...

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/171759.The_Apothecary_Rose?

Comment: @Valorum Correct, and it seems that I have completely misposted the question, since it is not a fantasy book at all... I must have mixed up the story with other books i read at the time...

Comment: @JoSSte - If you enjoyed these, you'll probably like the Didius Falco books; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Didius_Falco

Comment: @Valorum Thanks. Looks interesting,  I've added it to my goodreads "want to read"... I am just going to get through the Discworld first. ;-)

Comment: Is there a more appropriate SE site that this should be moved to? or should I delete it?

Comment: No need to delete it, it's goo that you found your answer ;)